# Why am I receiving a error when trying to use tkinter to make multiple windows gui?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create multiple window GUI application but can't open window.
i received an error.
when we run both window code separately it's run.
I don't know why this error occurs.
can anyone resolve this problem. and help me to run multiple frames in one window.

```
import tkinter as tk
import pywhatkit
import pyautogui


class automation(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.geometry("842x510")
        self.configure(bg="#ffffff")
        self.resizable(False, False)
        container = tk.Frame(self, background="#ffffff")
        container.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw')

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both")

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (mainwindow, SecondWindow):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

        self.show_frame('mainwindow')

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


def btn_clicked():
    print("Button Clicked")
```

This is my first window code

```
class mainwindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self, background="#ffffff")
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg="#ffffff", height=510, width=391, bd=0, 
                                highlightthickness=0, relief="ridge")
        self.canvas.place(x=0, y=0)
        self.canvas.pack(side='left')
        self.background_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="background.png")
        self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.background_img, anchor="nw")

        self.img1 = tk.PhotoImage(file="img1.png")
        self.b1 = tk.Button(self, image=self.img1, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(SecondWindow),
                        relief="flat")

        self.b1.place(x=392, y=100, width=348, height=62)
        self.b1.pack(padx=10, pady=125)

        # creating third button

        self.img3 = tk.PhotoImage(file="img3.png")
        self.b3 = tk.Button(self, image=self.img3, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, 
                            command=btn_clicked, relief="flat")

        self.b3.place(x=392, y=200, width=348, height=62)
        self.b3.pack(padx=10, pady=0)


        def send(num, msg, hour, minute):
        pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg(f"+91{num}", msg, hour, minute, 36)
        pyautogui.click()
        pyautogui.press("enter")
```

This is my Second window code

```
class SecondWindow(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, controller)

        a = tk.StringVar()
        b = tk.StringVar()
        c = tk.IntVar()
        d = tk.IntVar()

        self.frame = tk.Frame(self, background="#ffffff")
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg="#ffffff", height=510, width=842, bd=0, 
                                highlightthickness=0, relief="ridge")
        self.canvas.place(x=0, y=0)
        self.canvas.pack(side='left')
        self.canvas.pack()
        # set image in background
        self.background_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="background2.png")
        self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.background_img, anchor="nw")

        # enter a number
        self.entry1_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="textBox1.png")
        self.canvas.create_image(570, 112, image=self.entry1_img)

        self.entry1 = tk.Entry(bd=0, bg="#c4c4c4", highlightthickness=0, textvariable=a)
        self.entry1.place(x=423, y=90, width=280, height=45)

        # enter a massage

        self.entry2_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="textBox2.png")
        self.canvas.create_image(570, 225, image=self.entry2_img)

        self.entry2 = tk.Entry(bd=0, bg="#c4c4c4", highlightthickness=0, textvariable=b)

        self.entry2.place(x=423, y=203, width=280, height=45)

        # enter a time -> Hour
        self.entry3_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="textBox3.png")
        self.canvas.create_image(470, 329, image=self.entry3_img)

        self.entry3 = tk.Entry(bd=0, bg="#c4c4c4", highlightthickness=0, textvariable=c)

        self.entry3.place(x=423, y=312, width=80.0, height=35)

        # minute
        self.entry4_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="textBox4.png")
        self.canvas.create_image(676, 329, image=self.entry4_img)

        self.entry4 = tk.Entry(bd=0, bg="#c4c4c4", highlightthickness=0, textvariable=d)

        self.entry4.place(x=630, y=312, width=80.0, height=35)

        # Go home
        self.img4 = tk.PhotoImage(file="img4.png")
        self.b4 = tk.Button(image=self.img4, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(mainwindow), relief="flat")

        self.b4.place(x=418, y=400, width=100, height=37)

        # Send message
        self.img5 = tk.PhotoImage(file="img5.png")
        self.b5 = tk.Button(image=self.img5, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,
                        command=lambda: send(a.get(), b.get(), c.get(), d.get()), 
                           relief="flat")

        self.b5.place(x=642, y=400, width=100, height=37)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = automation()
    app.mainloop()
```

I received this Error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\myproject1\mix.py", line 140, in <module>
    app = automation()
  File "E:\myproject1\mix.py", line 21, in __init__
    frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
  File "E:\myproject1\mix.py", line 75, in __init__
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, controller)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 
3153, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'frame', cnf, {}, extra)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 
2601, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-menu"
```

please help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have passed extra argument `controller` to `tk.Frame.__init__(...)`:

```py
...
class SecondWindow(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        #tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, controller)
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent) # removed controller argument
        ...
```

Comment: can you please help me. after solving this error one more error is occur.    Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "E:\myproject1\mix.py", line 51, in <lambda>
    command=lambda: controller.show_frame(SecondWindow),
  File "E:\myproject1\mix.py", line 29, in show_frame
    frame = self.frames[page_name]
KeyError: <class '__main__.SecondWindow'>

Comment: Thankyou sir @acw1668 , It's Work.